# Cannot set private variable through constructor php

Tags: php, reference, private-members, private-methods, construct

I am trying to set private properties of Account class using _construct method. I tried using `this->` keyword but it gives me the same error. Here is my code.

```
<?php

class Account
{
    private $errorArray = array();
    private $userName;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $password;
    private $password2;
    private $role;
    //$userName, $firstName, $lastName, $password, $password2, $role
    function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['registerSubmit'])) {

            $userName = $_POST['userName'];
            $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
            $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
            $role = $_POST['role'];
        }
    }
    public function register()
    {
        checkUserName($userName, $errorArray);
        checkFirstName($firstName, $errorArray);
        checkLastName($lastName, $errorArray);
        checkPasswords($password, $password2, $errorArray);
        return $this->errorArray;
    }
```

the error says

> variable firstName is declared but never used. But I am clearly using it in the __construct and also in the next functions.

I tried:

> using `this->` inside constructor and even in parameters of
> checkUsername() like this `checkUserName(this-?$userName, this->errorsArray);`

the stranges part for me is

> when I return `$errorArray` in `register()` function it has no problem but
> when i try to access it in any other way it gives me errors.

Any help regarding this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need to use `$this->` before the property name to access a class’s properties, in all cases, no exceptions.

Comment: That also appears to be a warning, not an error, probably from your IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silly mistake I was making was in the syntax.
Need to use
`$this->variableName` instead of `this->$VariableName`.